# Cannot get pixelDelta from QWheelEvent in Qt5

Tags: python, events, qt5, pyqt5, mousewheel

I upgraded from Qt4 to Qt5 (PyQt, to be specific) and QWheelEvent broke for me - it returns empty pixelDelta(), but phase is at 2 (default). I am on Win 7, so the warning about phases shouldn't apply to me. When I run this code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Q(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pixelDelta())

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Q()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

scrolling prints 'PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()' without coordinates. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Qt5 docs for [QWheelEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html):

> There are two ways to read the wheel event delta: angleDelta() returns
>   the delta in wheel degrees. This value is always provided.
>   pixelDelta() returns the delta in screen pixels and is available on
>   platforms that have high-resolution trackpads, such as OS X.

There is no `pixelData` in Qt4. It only has [delta](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html#delta), and the equivalent Qt5 method to that is [angleDelta](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwheelevent.html#angleDelta).

Comment: Side note: as of today, Qt for Windows does not provide pixel delta even for high-precision trackpads. It is unfortunately not (yet?) implemented for Windows.